# what are working mutt pgp encryption commands?

Tags: gnupg, mutt

I have been using mutt for a while and while I can (and do) sign all of my emails, I cannot encrypt any emails.  I got my commands from some random place on the internet.  Here is my current setup.  I have reordered and formatted things so that they at least line up somewhat.

```
set pgp_sign_command        ="gpg --no-verbose --batch --output - --passphrase-fd 0 --armor --detach-sign --textmode %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_encrypt_only_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --output - --quiet           --armor               --textmode                             --always-trust --encrypt-to %a -r %r --encrypt %f"
set pgp_encrypt_sign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --output - --passphrase-fd 0 --armor               --textmode --encrypt --sign %?a?-u %a? --always-trust --encrypt-to %a -r %r -- %f"
```

When trying to encrypt a message I get this error:

```
usage: gpg [options] [filename]
```

When trying to sign and encrypt I get this error:

```
usage: gpg [options] --sign --encrypt [filename]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to **use the GPGME library**:

```
set crypt_use_gpgme
```

But if you want the old command method, **mutt itself comes with `/etc/Muttrc.gpg.dist`** containing example commands (the entire file included here):

```
# -*-muttrc-*-
#
# Command formats for gpg.
# 
# This version uses gpg-2comp from 
#   http://70t.de/download/gpg-2comp.tar.gz
#
# $Id$
#
# %p    The empty string when no passphrase is needed,
#       the string "PGPPASSFD=0" if one is needed.
#
#       This is mostly used in conditional % sequences.
#
# %f    Most PGP commands operate on a single file or a file
#       containing a message.  %f expands to this file's name.
#
# %s    When verifying signatures, there is another temporary file
#       containing the detached signature.  %s expands to this
#       file's name.
#
# %a    In "signing" contexts, this expands to the value of the
#       configuration variable $pgp_sign_as.  You probably need to
#       use this within a conditional % sequence.
#
# %r    In many contexts, mutt passes key IDs to pgp.  %r expands to
#       a list of key IDs.

# Note that we explicitly set the comment armor header since GnuPG, when used
# in some localiaztion environments, generates 8bit data in that header, thereby
# breaking PGP/MIME.

# decode application/pgp
set pgp_decode_command="gpg --status-fd=2 %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - %f"

# verify a pgp/mime signature
set pgp_verify_command="gpg --status-fd=2 --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - --verify %s %f"

# decrypt a pgp/mime attachment
set pgp_decrypt_command="gpg --status-fd=2 %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - %f"

# create a pgp/mime signed attachment
# set pgp_sign_command="gpg-2comp --comment '' --no-verbose --batch --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --detach-sign --textmode %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_sign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --detach-sign --textmode %?a?-u %a? %f"

# create a application/pgp signed (old-style) message
# set pgp_clearsign_command="gpg-2comp --comment '' --no-verbose --batch --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --textmode --clearsign %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_clearsign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --textmode --clearsign %?a?-u %a? %f"

# create a pgp/mime encrypted attachment
# set pgp_encrypt_only_command="pgpewrap gpg-2comp -v --batch --output - --encrypt --textmode --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_encrypt_only_command="pgpewrap gpg --batch --quiet --no-verbose --output - --encrypt --textmode --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"

# create a pgp/mime encrypted and signed attachment
# set pgp_encrypt_sign_command="pgpewrap gpg-2comp %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? -v --batch --output - --encrypt --sign %?a?-u %a? --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_encrypt_sign_command="pgpewrap gpg %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --batch --quiet --no-verbose --textmode --output - --encrypt --sign %?a?-u %a? --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"

# import a key into the public key ring
set pgp_import_command="gpg --no-verbose --import %f"

# export a key from the public key ring
set pgp_export_command="gpg --no-verbose --export --armor %r"

# verify a key
set pgp_verify_key_command="gpg --verbose --batch --fingerprint --check-sigs %r"

# read in the public key ring
set pgp_list_pubring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --with-colons --list-keys %r" 

# read in the secret key ring
set pgp_list_secring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --with-colons --list-secret-keys %r" 

# fetch keys
# set pgp_getkeys_command="pkspxycwrap %r"

# pattern for good signature - may need to be adapted to locale!

# set pgp_good_sign="^gpgv?: Good signature from "

# OK, here's a version which uses gnupg's message catalog:
# set pgp_good_sign="`gettext -d gnupg -s 'Good signature from "' | tr -d '"'`"

# This version uses --status-fd messages
set pgp_good_sign="^\\[GNUPG:\\] GOODSIG"
```